# Calculating probability of total score S in n dice rolls without brute force

Tags: probability

I came upon a problem where you're asked the probability of scoring 10 or higher in three dice(fair, six-sided) rolls.

The solution I found was 2/9, which was correct according to the source of the problem, but getting that answer required me to work through all possible cases.  I hoped the solution provided by my resource would show how to get the answer in a simpler way but it did the same thing(and so did several other resources I've found online).  But that brute force method of solving this problem is unsatisfying to me, and inelegant insofar as it can't be extended to intractably large numbers of rolls.

I've been enjoying taking my probability problems and writing python scripts that can calculate them for more general cases.  In this case, I'd be calculating the probability of a total score S after n rolls.  I want to learn how one would solve this problem without using brute force.

Thanks in advance, been learning a ton from perusing this website!

**Edit**:  Every answer provided has been tremendously useful to me and I am very grateful for everyone's effort.  I realize now that I have reworded the original problem incorrectly.

The exact wording of the original problem is:
"Your game piece is on the starting space, and the finish is 10 more spaces away. During each of your turns, you roll a fair six-sided die, and move that many spaces forward. However, if the result would put you past the finish, you do not move. What is the probability that you will reach the finish in 3 or fewer turns?"

In addition to still puzzling over the problem that I intended to ask about, I am now very interested in studying the problem I've inadvertently asked about, and I'm also now trying to work out exactly why my rephrasing was incorrect.

Again, thanks to everyone who responded, I cannot adequately express how much I appreciate the collective knowledge and generosity of this community.

Comment: Are you sure about that $2/9$ figure? I got that the sum of $3$ dice will give a value of $10$ or higher with probability $0.625$ and an empirical test confirmed that.

Comment: The average sum is 10.5 for three dice.  So by symmetry, the probability of 10 or higher must be above 50%.  I agree with Remy's value of 0.625.

Comment: See formulas for the cumulative distribution function of the binomial distribution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: Thank you. with your help and upon further reflection, I realize that I've improperly rephrased the problem that I was originally solving.  

The original problem was worded as follows:  
 "You need to advance 10 spaces on a game board.  What is the probability of doing so in 3 rolls or less?"

Comment: If you have a large number of die rolls (ten or more, say), then a Normal distribution gives a good approximation to the sum.  But I don't think you would get a good approximation with as few as three rolls.

Comment: A related problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649754/random-variables-proof-py-1y-2y-3-y-n-k-frac-1-mn-sum-1i-bino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the expansion of $(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x)^3$. When I calculate this I get

$$x^{18}+3x^{17}+6x^{16}+10x^{15}+15x^{14}+21x^{13}+25x^{12}+27x^{11}+27x^{10}+25x^{9}+21x^{8}+15x^{7}+10x^{6}+6x^{5}+3x^{4}+x^{3}$$

This says to me there are 10 ways to choose three items in $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ which sum to 15, since the coefficient $10$ is the number of ways to form the product $x^{15}$ from the product of $x^a x^b x^c = x^{a+b+c}$ where $a, b, c \in [1,6]$.

Is this brute force?

This expression tells us that there is a $\frac{1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 15 + 21 + 25 + 27}{6^3} = \frac{5}{8}$ chance of getting a sum of 10 or more.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: @ty. I'd be happy to. Can you be a little more specific about what you'd like me to elaborate on?

Comment: How does the  calculated correspond to your statement '(...) 10 ways to choose three items in $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ which sum to 15.'

Comment: Because of the properties of exponents, $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$. Then if our exponents are 1 to 6 this corresponds to the number of different products which have such a sum in their exponents. It's basically a direct application of the multinomial theorem.

Comment: @ty. I have edited the response. Please let me know if more elaboration would help.

Comment: Why do  the coefficients deliver the right amounts?

Comment: @ty. Perhaps you should perform by hand for a three-sided die rolled three times: $(x^3 + x^2 + x)^3$ and see how the arithmetic works. If you cannot see it immediately from a multinomial expansion I'm not sure how else to explain it. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd consider this an improvement, but you could take a recursive approach:

Let $P(n,k)$ be the probability of getting a sum of $n$ with $k$ rolls.

Then 
$$P(n,k)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot[P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-2,k-1)+P(n-3,k-1)+p(n-4,k-1)+P(n-5,k-1)+P(n-6,k-1)]$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this won't be useful to you as it is a brute force approach, but brute force can be used to find patterns. There are reoccurring patterns when considering sums of $n$ dice rolls. The columns indicate the number of dice rolls and the numbers underneath denote the number of ways to get a given total.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Total&1& 2 & 3 & 4 &5\\ \hline
1& 1& & &\\ \hline
2&  1& 1&&\\ \hline
3&  1& 2&1&\\ \hline
4&  1& 3&3&1\\ \hline
5&  1& 4&6&4&1\\ \hline
6&  1& 5&10&10&5\\ \hline
7&  & 6&15&20&15\\ \hline
8&  & 5&21&35&35\\ \hline
9&  & 4&25&56&70\\ \hline
10&  & 3&27&80&126\\ \hline
11&  & 2&27&104&205\\ \hline
12&  & 1&25&125&305\\ \hline
13&  & &21&140&420\\ \hline
14&  & &15&146&540\\ \hline
15&  & &10&140&651\\ \hline
16&  & &6&125&735\\ \hline
17&  & &3&104&780\\ \hline
18&  & &1&80&780\\ \hline
19&  & &&56&735\\ \hline
20&  & &&35&651\\ \hline
21&  & &&20&540\\ \hline
22&  & &&10&420\\ \hline
23&  & &&4&305\\ \hline
24&  & &&1&205\\ \hline
25&  & &&&126\\ \hline
26&  & &&&70\\ \hline
27&  & &&&35\\ \hline
28&  & &&&15\\ \hline
29&  & &&&5\\ \hline
30&  & &&&1\\ \hline
\end{array}